# How to create a new instance in exsisting stack AWS Cloudformation

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk

We've created an AWS Cloudformation Stack using AWS CDK (in Typescript).
The stack creates a new VPC, a new Security group & a new instance. (1)

We've deployed this stack using `cdk deploy` command.

Now we want to add a second instance to that stack. We are unable to find a source that explains how this can be done.

We can create a new stack using the VPC, security group created in (1). And create a new instance in this new stack.

This way we can add instances to the same VPC and security group but not the same stack.

We cannot create all the instances in the stack at the time of the creation of the stack.

Is this the only way we can new instances to existing VPCs?

Can't we add new instances to the existing stack using AWS CDK (in Typescript)?

Comment: Do you understand the CDK code you have written? Re-write that code to not create only one instance but two.

Comment: Yes, but my requirement is different here. Need to create a new instance whenever required. Can't create all the instances at the time of the creation of the stack.

Comment: No idea what you mean / want. How should cloudformation know when a new instances is required? Add a InstacenCount parameter, use it and update the stack whenever you want.

Comment: We have a stack. It has a VPC, a security group, and an instance. We don't delete the existing instance. We want to add a new instance to the stack.

Comment: "add a new instance to the stack" is not how anything works. You can change the stack to provision one more instance. You can do that by either explicitly writing code to create a second instance within the stack or by e.g. creating a parameter that controls how many instances you want.

Comment: You probably need to create an Autoscaling Group. You will also need a Launch Template and a Target Group

Comment: Assuming you really do mean that you simply want to add an EC2 instance, you update your CDK code to indicate the 2nd instance, use `cdk diff` to verify the changes, then re-run `cdk deploy` which will deploy the changes.

Comment: Maybe what you need is Autoscaling Group. You can create autoscaling group using the CDK. Autoscaling group csn spawn instances when needed. Are you familiar with the concept of Autoscaling group?

Answer (score 0):

I can't recall what the file name is in typescript (in python it is the app.py) where you define your stacks, you either define a second one of the same Stack (remember a stack is just a class so you instantiate a second version)

It seems however you want to be able to spin up as many as you want in demand. In that case, the ID string of your stack props defines the stacks name in Cloudformation. You can make that a formated string that takes a context variable. You can then deploy using `cdk deploy -c variable=value`

So, for instance (sorry it's in python but the idea remains the same)

```
from my_stack import MainStack
 
context_var = app.try_get_context("stack_id")

a_stack = MainStack(
     app, f"Main-{context_var}")
```

You would then deploy with `cdk deploy Main-\* -c stack_id=SomeString`

Then every different value will spin up a new stack. Reusing an old value will update an old stack. We use this to allow devs to spin up a "local" version of the stack with their work username attached. Since it deploys from their local it uses their code from their branch and they can test big changes before merging to the dev branch ie `Main-Lynkfox` and `Main-Penguin` would be deployed with `-c stack_id=Lynkfox` and `-c stack_id=Penguin` respectively

You will of course either need to append that value on to every name of every resource inside the stack or let cdk choose the resource names. If you go with the former I recommend creating a common properties object you can pass into each stack to use within.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/context.html

To tie it back to typesceipt, the example here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/latest/guide/stacks.html with stack1 and stack2 - you replace those with variable defined strings. Since that is also how you tell cdk deploy which stack to deploy, it's good to prefix like I did above

Edit: since your stack is vpc and security group, and you will need those values for other stacks, the other option here is to make it a `NestedStack` that you then create and reference it's properties inside another stack

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-cloudformation.NestedStack.html